# When a client access a file on a server, how is the file prepared before transfer?

Tags: server, client, client-server

If someone clicks a download link on a website, to download a file on the website's server (direct download link), is the file uploaded to the internet by your ISP (copy made) and then transferred to the client or is the file read so many bytes at a time and transferred from server drive to client side?

I'm asking because I want to know, if someone starts downloading a file from my server, can I delete the file while the download is going on or must the file exists for the entirety of the download...

Server is Apache.

Comment: That depends on the server implementation and cannot be answered generally.

Comment: The server is Apache.